# Buildozer sqlite3 operational error

Tags: python, sqlite, kivy, buildozer

I'm trying to debug and deploy a kivy app to my (android) phone using buildozer. Part of the app is a map (mapview using mbtiles) that requires sqlite3. Doing some research I found that I need to have

```
requirements = kivy,sqlite3,futures,requests,openssl
```

When I deploy my app and open the map, it crashes with the following error message

```
I/python  (13917):  sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

The path that points to the database is full length. I changed the file permissions to rw-rw-rw- and rwxrwxrwx of the database and the folder that contains the database (they were rw-rw-r-- / rwxrwxr-- before). I did this in the folder .buildozer/android/app/"databasefolder"/database. It still doesn't work and I wonder whether this is the correct way to change file permissions.
Do I need to change anything in the android.permissions of the spec file?

I'm not the only one who had this problem, but the suggested solutions do not work for me or I'm not doing the right thing.

Could there be any other reason why the database cannot be opened?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Where are you trying to open it?

Comment: I wrote the kivy app on my Windows computer and there it works fine. I use a virtual machine (Ubuntu) to deploy the app to my phone. When I open it there, it crashes.

Comment: Yes, but where are you trying to open the file? What is its location?

Comment: Sorry, the database (.mbtiles) is located in .buildozer/android/app/map/ and the mapview class that is trying to open it, is in .buildozer/android/app/libs/garden/garden.mapview/mapview and called mbtsource.py. I think the filename variable (path) that is passed on to mbtsource.py is correct but it fails to do self.db = sqlite3.connect(filename).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the simple answer in this case is that a relative path to the db should be given.